# Android Navigation Bar: Как при повторном выборе элемента на панели навигации переходить к основному фрагменту?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, bottom-navigation-view

Нашел такой [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68777836/14519908) с таким [ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73698804/14519908) в котором идеально описано необходимое мне поведение навигационной панели.

> Поведение:
>
> `Home` -> `Detail Page A` -> `Detail Page B` затем на панели навигации нажимаем `Home` -> `Home`
>
> `Home` -> `Detail Page A` -> `Detail Page B` затем нажимаем `Profile` на панели навигации, далее
> снова `Home`. Отображается `Detail Page B`, затем еще раз `Home`
> сработает как в первом случае (вернет обратно на фрагмент `Home`)

Здесь `Home` и `Profile` — фрагменты, привязанные к кнопкам на панели навигации, а `Detail Page` `A` и `B` — дочерние фрагменты, в которые можно перейти из `Home`

Код из ответа:

```kotlin
navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_container)

binding.navView.setOnItemReselectedListener { menuItem ->              
   val selectedMenuItemNavGraph = 
       navController.graph.findNode(menuItem.itemId) as NavGraph              

   selectedMenuItemNavGraph.let { menuGraph ->           
       navController.popBackStack(menuGraph.startDestinationId, false)              
   }          
}
```

Но когда я пытаюсь выполнить его, получаю ошибку:

```
androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator$Destination cannot be cast to androidx.navigation.NavGraph
```

Это связано с тем, что `navController.graph.findNode(menuItem.itemId)` возвращает тип `NavDestination`, который нельзя привести к `NavGraph`

Как можно решить эту проблему по-другому?